# List Interval Sum

Tags: list-manipulation

I am doing a large data-set computation. Among those computational steps, in one step I need to do a sum with a pattern: Sum the elements with same interval.

For example, for a list from 1 to 9;  With the interval being **set to 3 manually**. So it could be other values in different cases.

And the list would be calculated as:

```
1 + 4 + 7 = 12;
2 + 5 + 8 = 15;
3 + 6 + 9 = 18;
```

So for `list = Range[1,9]`,the final desired result would be `{12,15,18}` in this example. I attached an illustration for a further elaboration: sum the element with the same color when interval = 3:

[image: The example illustration, sum same color with interval equals to 3 in this case]

Thanks for @Chris's Answer, the above case could be solved by:

```
 Total[Partition[Range[9], 3]]
```

**Edit my original question from here:**

But what I actually want to do is only sum "N" numbers in a time. N is settled and when N = 3 in below example:

[image]

It should be computed by :

```
1 + 4 + 7 = 12;
2 + 5 + 8 = 15;
3 + 6 + 9 = 18;
10 + 13 + 16 = 39;
11 + 14 + 17 = 42;
12 + 15 + 18 = 45;
```

Hereby the result would be `{12,15,18,39,42,45}`

I think this might be not hard, but I just can't think it very clearly when I want to utilize the parallelization characteristics of MMA and trying to avoid `Unpacked Array` results.

Comment: is the length of the input list always a multiple of  `n`? If not, what is the desired output for inputs  `Range[19]` and `Range[20]`?

Comment: The length of list will always be `Mod[Length[list],N] = 0`, so no worry about corner cases

Answer (score 4):

```
Total[Partition[Range[9], 3]]
```

> {12, 15, 18}

Update for revised question:

```
r = Range[18]    

Total /@ Flatten[Partition[#, 3] & /@ {r[[1 ;; ;; 3]], r[[2 ;; ;; 3]], r[[3 ;; ;; 3]]}, 1]
```

Comment: Hi Chris, sorry I wasn't clarify the problem clearly. I just updated my question would you still interest to help?

Answer (score 3):

Using the six-argument form of `Partition`:

```
Join @@ Partition[Partition[Range[9], 3], 3, 3, {1, 1}, {}, Plus]
```

> {12, 15, 18}

```
Join @@ Partition[Partition[Range[18], 3], 3, 3, {1, 1}, {}, Plus]
```

> {12, 15, 18, 39, 42, 45}

More generally,

```
ClearAll[partsums]
partsums[lst_List, n_Integer] := Join@@Partition[Partition[lst, n], n, n, {1,1}, {}, Plus]
```

**Examples:**

```
partsums[Range[18], 3]
```

> {12, 15, 18, 39, 42, 45}

```
Grid[Prepend[Table[{i, Column[i Range[7]], Column[partsums[Range@#, i] & /@ 
    (i Range[7])]}, {i, {3, 4, 5}}], {"n", "Length@list" , "f[list, n]"}], 
    Alignment -> Center, Dividers -> All] // TeXForm
```

> $\small\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
> \hline
>  \text{n} & \text{Length@list} & \text{f[list, n]} \\
> \hline
>  3 & 
> \begin{array}{l}
>  3 \\
>  6 \\
>  9 \\
>  12 \\
>  15 \\
>  18 \\
>  21 \\
> \end{array}
>  & 
> \begin{array}{l}
>  \{1,2,3\} \\
>  \{5,7,9\} \\
>  \{12,15,18\} \\
>  \{12,15,18,10,11,12\} \\
>  \{12,15,18,23,25,27\} \\
>  \{12,15,18,39,42,45\} \\
>  \{12,15,18,39,42,45,19,20,21\} \\
> \end{array}
>  \\
> \hline
>  4 & 
> \begin{array}{l}
>  4 \\
>  8 \\
>  12 \\
>  16 \\
>  20 \\
>  24 \\
>  28 \\
> \end{array}
>  & 
> \begin{array}{l}
>  \{1,2,3,4\} \\
>  \{6,8,10,12\} \\
>  \{15,18,21,24\} \\
>  \{28,32,36,40\} \\
>  \{28,32,36,40,17,18,19,20\} \\
>  \{28,32,36,40,38,40,42,44\} \\
>  \{28,32,36,40,63,66,69,72\} \\
> \end{array}
>  \\
> \hline
>  5 & 
> \begin{array}{l}
>  5 \\
>  10 \\
>  15 \\
>  20 \\
>  25 \\
>  30 \\
>  35 \\
> \end{array}
>  & 
> \begin{array}{l}
>  \{1,2,3,4,5\} \\
>  \{7,9,11,13,15\} \\
>  \{18,21,24,27,30\} \\
>  \{34,38,42,46,50\} \\
>  \{55,60,65,70,75\} \\
>  \{55,60,65,70,75,26,27,28,29,30\} \\
>  \{55,60,65,70,75,57,59,61,63,65\} \\
> \end{array}
>  \\
> \hline
> \end{array}$

Answer (score 2):

```
Total@Take[Range@9, {#, -1, 3}] & /@ Range@3
```

> {12, 15, 18}

or..

```
Total /@ Transpose@Partition[Range@9, 3]
```

> {12, 15, 18}